# Testing throw error inside generator?

Tags: javascript, testing, redux, generator, redux-saga

I am trying to test the thrown of an error inside a generator function as follow, using Jest and Chai:

```
    // function

    function * gen () {
        yield put({ type: TIME_OUT_LOGOUT })
        throw new Error('User has logged out')
    }

    //test

    let genFunc = gen()

    expect(genFunc().next).to.deep.equal(put({ type: TIME_OUT_LOGOUT }))

    expect(genFunc().next).to.throw(Error('User has logged out'));
```

But it isn't working. Which would be the correct way to test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your testing code from `genFunc().next` to `genFunc.next().value`

---

**EDIT:**

The assertions should be:

`expect(genFunc.next().value).toEqual(put({type: TIME_OUT_LOGOUT}));
expect(genFunc.next).toThrow(Error);`

For the second assertion `expect(() => genFunc.next()).toThrow(Error);` would also work, but the wrapper function `() => genFunc.next()` is unnecessary since `genFunc.next` does not take any parameters.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, which in fact make sens since the generator function has no other next.value, because no other yield is left.

Comment: Is your first assertion working? In any case, I've made a correction. The following is working for me (using Jasmine syntax): `expect(genFunc.next().value).toEqual(put({ type: TIME_OUT_LOGOUT }));
expect(() => genFunc.next()).toThrow(Error('User has logged out'));`Notice the wrapper function around `genFunc.next()` in the second assertion.

Comment: Ok, I get it workin, changin the assertion to: 
expect(genFunc.next().value).toEqual(put({ type: TIME_OUT_LOGOUT })); expect(() => genFunc.next()).toThrow(Error);
If you want post your answer so I can mark it as the solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I could help